# Django-cms custom user permission based on field data

Tags: python, django, content-management-system, django-cms

I saw there are some user permission type for me to select but I am thinking if I can have my own custom permission setting.

I am trying to build a cms system having several users from different areas. Each of them cant delete data input by other users and each of the will input data with a field indicating it is a data from whom.

Do I have to code it myself or Django-cms actually provides this option.

If references could be provided, it would be the best.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django CMS (at least in the latest version) provides this option. From the docs:

> **Page permissions**
>
> The Page permission formset has multiple checkboxes defining different
>   permissions: can edit, can add, can delete, can change advanced
>   settings, can publish, can move and can change permission. These
>   define what kind of actions the user/group can do on the pages on
>   which the permissions are being granted through the Grant on
>   drop-down.
>
> Can change permission refers to whether the user can change the
>   permissions of his subordinate users. Bob is the subordinate of Alice
>   if one of:
>
> Bob was created by Alice Bob has at least one page permission set on
>   one of the pages on which Alice has the Can change permissions right
>   Note: Mind that even though a new user has permissions to change a
>   page, that doesn’t give him permissions to add a plugin within that
>   page. In order to be able to add/change/delete plugins on any page,
>   you will need to go through the usual Auth.User model and give the new
>   user permissions to each plugin you want him to have access to.
>   Example: if you want the new user to be able to use the text plugin,
>   you will need to give him the following rights: text | text | Can add
>   text, text | text | Can change text, text | text | Can delete text.

[Here's the link to the permissions page](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/3.2.2/topics/permissions.html#id1) of the docs, which go into a bit more detail on limiting a user's ability to add/edit plugins and templates, and other fun stuff.